# Dependency manager for Web

Tags: javascript, bower

I have 2 projects. They use same js/img files. When I change js content in first project I should also change it in second project. I wanna make it as dependency. So I `deploy` changes to my local repository, then goto project1/project2, call `update` and changes are loaded.

I have tried to use [bower](https://github.com/twitter/bower) but it doesn't satisfy me because of some strange behaviour (it copies whole folder content and ignores `main` section in `component.json`)

How can I implement normal dependency managment in my project? ***note: I need to manage my local dependencies***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` property in `component.json` is currently only used for other tools using Bower. There is currently a [discussion](https://github.com/twitter/bower/issues/88) going if Bower should have a `.bowerignore` file for ignoring files it doesn't need.

You might be better of just using a git submodule or symlinking the files.

Alternatively you could check out if any of the other JS package managers fills your need: [npm](https://npmjs.org/), [Ender](http://ender.jit.su/), [volo](http://volojs.org/), [component](https://github.com/component/component), [jam](http://jamjs.org)

Answer (score 1):

Another option (if you just want to fetch single files) might be: [pulldown](https://github.com/jackfranklin/pulldown).

Configuration is extremely simple and you can easily add your own files/urls to the list.